# Запуск nodejs процессов на одном сервере с разными IP

Tags: node.js, ip, steam

Имеется один сервер с 3-мя IP адресами. Имеются nodejs процессы (боты для steam).
Как их запустить под разными IP?

Answer (score 3):

### Server

> `server.listen([port][, hostname][, backlog][, callback])`
> [HTTP Nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server)

Параметр `hostname` отвечает за прослушиваемый интерфейс.
По умолчанию, слушает все: IPv4 `0.0.0.0` или IPv6 `::`.

Укажите для каждого сервера IP своего сетевого интерфейса.

## Client

> `http.request(options[, callback])`
> `options.localAddress` - (bind) Интерфейс с которого отправляются запросы
> [HTTP Request Nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  hostname: 'example.org',
  localAddress: '127.35.17.221'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
  });
});
```

Comment: как я понимаю, вы показываете взаимосвязь между двумя процессами Nodejs. А мне нужно немного другое. Есть библиотеки с которыми я работаю, типа node-steam. Он как я понимаю делает запросы на сервера steam. Вот как сделать так, чтобы он отправлял эти запросы под нужным мне айпи? Соответственно не правив код самих библиотек

Comment: Нет, я написал как прибиндить к интерфейсу клиентское или серверное приложение. Смотря что у вас там. Не все в курсе, что у вас за steam-бот.

Comment: библиотека подключает var request = require('request'); И посылает запросы через этот модуль. Так вот может быть можно в начала главного скрипта указать, чтобы все запросы через request были с нужным мне айпи. Если так можно, то подскажите как это сделать. Никак не могу найти инфу

Comment: request - обёртка над http. там те же опции. `var request = require('request').defaults({localAddress: '127.35.13.89'})`

Comment: я проверил, то этот айпи будет использоваться только в главном файле, а в библиотеках все равно будет использоваться старый айпи. Как же сделать так, чтобы во всем проекте все request запросы были под нужным айпи?